# Extend FontAwesome with IcoMoon

Tags: meteor, font-awesome, icon-fonts

In a project with the Meteor javascript framework, I'm using Fontawesome to display my icons. 
I want to add my custom icons to FontAwesome. Looking around, I understand that IcoMoon is exactly the tool I need.

But I don't understand how I can add an icon taken in IcoMoon to FontAwesome.

Can someone help me :)

Thanks

Comment: Seriously?!.....https://icomoon.io/docs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a meteor question, but an icomoon question. The answer is that you don't add an icomoon set to font-awesome, rather you let them run together side by side.

What is meteor specific is how you can access those fonts, so they will need to be in your `/public/`directory.

You can find an example of this through my [meteor starter set](https://github.com/thatgibbyguy/tgg-meteor-boilerplate/tree/master/app/public). You would put your extracted icomoon fonts inside of that `/assets/` directory. Then inside of [`/client/less/`](https://github.com/thatgibbyguy/tgg-meteor-boilerplate/tree/master/app/client/less) (or sass if you use that) you would put your icomoon file as an import. Finally from your [main less file](https://github.com/thatgibbyguy/tgg-meteor-boilerplate/blob/master/app/client/styles.less) you would import the file like `@import "/less/icomoon.import.less";` at the top of your document.

Comment: Thanks. well explained :)